# how to catch error when api call fails in angular 2

Tags: angular, api, rxjs

I'm developing an app that scans qr codes. I have a service dedicated to the scanner device where I get the data scanned.

```
this.dataWedge.scanResult$
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
        filter(_ => this.assignState.getAssign() === this.assignState.Default),
        switchMap(scanData =>
          this.api.callApi(
            PurchaseOrderQuery,
            {
              DataString: scanData.DataString
            }
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(purchaseOrder => {
        this.scannedResult$.next(purchaseOrder);
      });
```

The problem is that when I pass a datastring that doesn't exist in the database, the api call fails (as it should be), but it never goes in the subscribe. How can I catch the error response from the api when this fails? Is it because of the `switchMap` maybe?

Comment: You need to use `catchError` after `switchMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscriptions have three callbacks :

```
xxx().subscribe(
  response => { ... }, // Request completed
  error => { ... }, // Request error
  () => { ... }, // Triggered in any case (like a "finally" from a try-catch block)
);
```

This is how you manage errors.

You can also keep your stream going with `catchError` :

```
xxx().pipe(
  catchError(err => of('some value')),
);
```

This will continue the stream with "some value" instead of the value of your stream.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't catch the error. In Network I see that the call fails but I can't seem to get it

Comment: I've tried both, I subscribe from a component to get the result and bind it to the html. 
here's the subscription but I get scanData = null instead of catching the error.
https://pastebin.com/WEM1pfhQ

Answer (score 1):

here it an example

```
     this.dataWedge.scanResult$
     .pipe(
     tap(_ => (this.scanning = false)),
     filter(_ => this.assignState.getAssign() === this.assignState.Default),
     switchMap(scanData =>
       this.api.callApi(
        PurchaseOrderQuery,
        {
          DataString: scanData.DataString
        }
      )
     )
    )
    .subscribe(purchaseOrder => {
     this.scannedResult$.next(purchaseOrder);
    }, err {
           console.log(err); // here you will get the error if api call fails 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. After the switchMap it won't go into the subscribe. It goes to another subscribe that I call from another component to bind the html with the result from the api, and I get it null

Comment: if you write error section in another component subscribe then is it working for you or you have to use catchError section for this?

Comment: I subscribe from a component to get the result and bind it to the html. here's the subscription but I get scanData = null instead of catching the error. pastebin.com/WEM1pfhQ

Comment: can you remove the pipe and try again

Comment: the status is 200

Comment: This is the problem my friend:) you need to change the api response status. Currently it gives 200 that means success so on angular side it doesn’t go into error sections if backend give us status like 400 on that time our angular side code is execute the error section:) it would be great if you accept my ans so other dev knows this might be an issue

Comment: ok i solved it. It was a stupid error in the build. Now after the switchMap, it goes in the error. But if I want to access the error from another component, how would I do that?